# How to search for a file by name pattern and execute a command in its directory?

Tags: find, quoting

What the following command should do, is to search for all invoice pdf files and check if there is a thumbnail file inside the same directory. If not, it should print the directory. Later I will add a command which will create the thumbnails.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "invoice_*.pdf" -exec sh -c '[ -f "$(dirname {})/thumbnail.jpeg" ] || echo {}' ';'
```

The command is working, but I besides the filepath I see the following

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I guess the filepath gets interpreted as command.

Comment: maybe you should use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, then you wouldn't need to use `$(dirname {})` (you can just test `[ -f ./thumbnail.jpeg ]`)

Comment: `-execdir` is a good idea, but I need the path to the pdf file. when I use `-execdir`, `{}` contains only the filename like `./invoice_19805.pdf`

Comment: and it's not solving the described problem :(

Comment: are there any `(` or `)` characters in the `invoice_*.pdf` filenames?  try double-quoting the `{}` in the echo statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `(` in one of your files names and are not quoting.

Try:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -exec sh -c '[ -f "$(dirname '"'{}'"')/thumbnail.jpeg" ] || echo "{}"' \;
```

The quotception going on with `'"'{}'"'` is to pass double quotes through to the dirname command in case there is a `(` in the file name. 
The `'[ -f .. ]'` command also needs double quotes and the echo command also needs quotes!

It may be easier to use `find` to call a script and pass it the path as an argument so you don't have to think about multiple layers of quoting and substitution. For example (not tested):

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash --
dir=$(dirname "${1}")
[ -f "${dir}/thumbnail.jpeg" ] || echo "${1}" 

$ find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -exec ./script '{}' \;
```